# Do flat flexible connectors (FFC) couplers exist? (i.e. I don't want to use a cable)

Tags: connector, ffc

I'm working on an electronic design where I have a motherboard that allows daughter boards to connect to it. The motherboard and daughter boards should be parallel to one another.

Because my design must be minimally flat (~0.25"), I'm having a difficult time finding a correct connector type. The connector I'm looking for must have 9 (10 is okay) conductors. The width of this connector is ideally less than an inch.

I have stumbled across flat flex connector (FFCs) and am genuinely interested. This would add the benefit of allowing the daughter boards to extend a distance past the board if I decide to use an flat flex cable. This is very useful in my application.

However, there times where I may simply want to connect the daughter board as close as possible to the motherboard. In this case, I would not want to use a cable, but I would rather user a rigid coupler.

Do they make couplers for FFCs such that I can connect to FFC closely together?

Thanks!

Comment: google "pcb to pcb low profile connectors"

Comment: @EugeneSh I've been looking for a connector that fit's my requirements for the past week. Nothing has stuck out as being a good option.

Comment: Do you want to stack the boards or line them up?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I would like to line them up.

Comment: What's wrong with something like [this](http://canada.newark.com/samtec/ssw-106-02-g-s-ra/board-to-board-connector-right/dp/15P2891?CMP=KNC-GCA-GEN-SHOPPING-VCC&CAGPSPN=pla&CATCI=aud-191015087572:pla-18283950120&gclid=Cj0KEQjw0MW9BRDxtYTn2_S699MBEiQAw33y49HlnbC8Q9a8c26HIAPUc8qwY3KYrLGqI_D36f8semEaAhqh8P8HAQ&CAAGID=23350543732&mckv=f4Jzft6A&CAWELAID=120185770000448513)?

Comment: To echo Eugene Sh., there are some very low profile board stacking options out there, and Samtec is likely the best source for them.  I've also seen snap-in FFC connectors in some cell phones, if that sparks any thought. If you have a dead smartphone around, rip it open and you may find some ideas on how to accomplish a low profile multi-level design.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Do they make these in slightly higher densities? The width of a 10 conductor connector would be 1" wide, I'm aiming for 3/4"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could modify your daughter boards to be made of flexible circuits (with possible solid areas if required) so that the daughter board thin edge is the actual flexible flat cable.  You could then position them at suitable orientation and proximity to the main board and have a measure of alignment and vibration tolerance in the placement.

You could get ideas from the following [Google picture search](https://www.google.com/search?q=flex%20rigid%20pcb&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch).

**EDIT:**
This [link](http://www.ats.net/products-technology/product-portfolio/flexible-rigid-flexible-pcbs/rigid-flexible-pcbs/) has a picture that illustrates what I had in mind.